# Find the 3 radius in the picture below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

If ABCD is a square show that: $r1=\frac{l}{16}$, $r2 = \frac{l}{6}$ and $r3 = \frac{3l}{8}$

My progress:
[image]

Euclid's Theorem:
$\triangle AO2D\\
AO_2^2=DO_2^2+l^2-2r_2l\implies(l+r_2)^2 = (l-r_2)^2+l^2-2r_2l\\
6lr_2 = l^2 \therefore \boxed{ r_2=\frac{l}{6}}$

$\triangle AJI: (l-r_3)^2=r_3^2+(\frac{l}{2})^2 \implies l^2-2lr_3+r_3^2=r_3^2+\frac{l^2}{4}\\
4l^2-8lr_3=l^2\rightarrow 3l^2 = 8lr_3\therefore \boxed{r_3=\frac{3l}{8}}
$

I can demonstrate $r2$ and $r3$ the Radius $r1$ are missing

Comment: Just for the record, you could also have $r_4$ between $r_3$ and $r_1$, and $r_5$ between $A$ and $r_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $r_1$ you can use Pythagoras:

$$\left(\frac{l}{2}\right)^2+(l-r_1)^2=(l+r_1)^2$$

This gives the required result straightaway.

Likewise, for $r_3$,

$$r_3^2+\left(\frac{l}{2}\right)^2=(l-r_3)^2$$

Comment: What guarantees that the hypotenuse passes through the point of tangency?

Comment: the hypotenuse you refer to is collinear with a common diameter for both circles and since the diameter is perpendicular to the tangent, the tangents for both circles coincide as one line. Therefore the tangent point and both centres are collinear.

Comment: thanks for explanation

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, for $r_3$, use Pythagoras on the triangle whose hypotenuse is the segment from $A$ to the center of that circle and whose third vertex is the point of tangency of that circle with $AD$, giving
$$(l-r_3)^2 = r_3^2 + \left(\frac{l}{2}\right)^2.$$

Comment: What guarantees that the hypotenuse passes through the point of tangency?

Comment: The tangent $AD$ is perpendicular to the radius, so the line from $A$ to the center is the hypotenuse of the right triangle.